# Get A Value From Url parameter And Save It in txt file

Tags: php

I want to save a value from url parameter

into txt file on server.

```php
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

I am getting value Dont know how to Save It in a Txt File.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is open a file and write the contents:

```
 $fd = fopen("FILENAME","w");
 fwrite($fd, $id);
 fclose($fd);
```

Look at the PHP manual: [PHP Filesystem funcions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$filename = 'test.txt';
if ($handle = fopen($filename, "w")) {
    fwrite($handle, $id);
}
fclose($handle);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way

```
$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = $id;
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you have to open a file:

```
$datei_handle=fopen("part_of_url.txt",w);
```

Make Sure you use the right Mode!
Write your stuff if that.

```
fwrite($datei_handle,$your_url_part);
```

Close the file.

```
fclose($datei_handle);
```

Also check the Manuel. Pretty good explanation there I think.
http://php.net/manual/de/function.fwrite.php

Hope that help.